# "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received." Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension and am trying to create a connection between my background and content script, but `chrome.runtime.lastError is set to:

`The message port closed before a response was received.`

I have followed this solution [How to implement "return true;"? Error: "The message port closed before a response was received."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54736574/12119984), and added 'return true' to mark it as aynschronous to keep the port open but am still getting an error. Here is my code

bacground.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  var message = { message: "tab has been updated, read HTML from tab" };
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, message);

  //send second message
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
    tabId,
    { tabCreated: "true" },
    function (response) {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError){
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError)
      }
      console.log("received response from context page", response)
      contextPageWidth = response.pageWidth
    });

});
```

content.js

```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sendResponse) => {
    sendResponse({pageWidth:"100"})
    return true;
  });
```

Anyone know where i am going wrong?

Comment: This is basically a typo: you've missed `sender` parameter after `request`, see the documentation. BTW you don't need `return true` here. Also remove the first chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, message);

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "sender" parameter to your event listener like so:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
        sendResponse({message:foo})
        return true;
      });
```

For further documentation please visit: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/